# JavaScript for GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a validation for gridview row Selection.

There is a "Delete" button and a GridView, in that GridView, there is a "Select" LinkButton column.

I am trying to create a validation for that, When clicking on the "Delete" Button, If the particular row in GridViewis not selected for deleting, then it should show a alert message i.e. "First select any row to delete."

So I wrote a code for the validation:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
function validateGridSelection() {

    var GridSelectedID = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');

    if(GridSelectedID.rows.selectedIndex = -1) {
        alert("First select any row to delete");
        return false;
    }
}
```

`</script>`

But this JavaScript is not working for this validation.

So, Please help me out to sort out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is an error being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Is your GridSelectedID getting the grid control?
If not try making your grid ClientIDMode="Static".

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
function confirmBox() 
    {
        var index = <%=grdMTHints.SelectedIndex%>;
        if (index > -1) 
        {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
        }
        else 
        {
            alert('Plese select row to be deleted.');
        }
    }

<asp:Button 
        ID="btnDelete" CssClass="buttonStyle" runat="server" Text="Delete"  CommandName="Delete"         
        OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmBox();" 
        ToolTip="Delete selected row." onclick="btnDelete_Click"/>
```